# pass data from intentservice to activity that is about to be start

Tags: android, intentservice

I have an intenetService that is running even when application is 'killed' and scaning for changes in my database -when change accures "notification" is pushed -now when I click on notification ,application starts and I would like to pass that result from intenetservice to that Activity any suggestioins -I'm giessing I could do that with -I think I could use SharedPreferences -but guessing it's not ideal
P.S
when activity is alive I retrive data with help of ResultReciver-but like I said it doesn't work when activity is killed:S

Comment: use "bound local service" pattern

Comment: @pskink ty -looking it up at once! (y)

Comment: @pskink reading documentation for bound services now : "A bound service typically lives only while it serves another application component and does NOT run in the background  INDEFINITELY" -my intentservice starts every 5min indefinitely -is that not gona be a problem?

Comment: no, a service can both be started and bound at one time